# How can I programmatically span columns in a tablelayout?

Tags: android, html, tablelayout, seekbar

I have a dynamic tablelayout that I build programmatically.  Every so often one of the rows has a child SeekBar.

Any suggestions for how I can programmatically make these SeekBars span across all the table columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This should get you going in the right direction, it asks Android to manage the column for you and stretch it if there is room on the row.

```
public void setColumnStretchable(int columnIndex, boolean isStretchable)
```

**Source:**

[developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setColumnStretchable%28int,%20boolean%29)